# How to open Firefox 3.6.13 without titlebar

Tags: c++, firefox, firefox-addon, ubuntu-10.04, firefox3.6

I need to remove the Titlebar in Firefox 3.6.13 window.  I googled and found this link: http://www.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html

I realized removing the Title Bar is possible by changing the file **userChrome.css** in this Path :

> /home/../.mozilla/firefox/../chrome/userChrome.css

but I could not find the syntax to write in **userChrome.css**. How I can solve it ?

Comment: You want fullscreen? hit F11.

Comment: I knew it but i want to completely hide it from user

Comment: Are you sure that it is actually the "Title Bar" which you want to hide?  It is likely that what you are trying to do is not what you have described.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** This answer was provided prior to it being known that the question was about Firefox 3.6.13 (mentioned for the first time in the comments to this answer). After that comment was made, I edited the question and title to include that significant piece of information. This answer has been left here in case someone looking for the information for current versions of Firefox happens to land on this page as the result of a search.

---

For the last few/several versions of Firefox (from Firefox 29.0), the "Title Bar" has been hidden by default.

You can hide/unhide the "Title Bar" from the customization dialog which can be reached by clicking on the icon on the far right of the toolbar containing the urlbar. This icon, by default, looks like 3 horizontal lines.  You will then need to click "Customize" (bottom left of popup).  The button to display/hide the "Title Bar" is on the bottom left of the window which will be displayed within the browser upon hitting customize.

You can also directly change the option to show the "Title Bar".  In `about:config` (enter `about:config` in the urlbar) you can change the state of `browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar`.

Comment: well I tried to change browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar but my firefox version is 3.6.13 on ubuntu and dose not have this option

Comment: @Unix2000, Firefox 3.6.13 was released on 2010-12-03.  Is there a reason that you are using a version which is nearly 4 years old?

Comment: Firefox 3.6 has open security holes and is not safe to use on the internet. You really should upgrade.